# Python : TypeError when i'm using this piece of code:

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror

```
for i in itemBaskets.values():
    for j in aprioriList:
        if all(item in sorted(i) for item in sorted(j)) is True:
            if j not in hashTable:
                hashTable[j] = 1
            else:
                hashTable[j] += 1
```

The error I get is :

```
    if all(item in sorted(i) for item in sorted(j)) is True:
TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable
```

Why do I get this error when I'm trying to count the appearances of every element of list `aprioriList` as a subset of `i`?

Comment: What types of values are in `itemBaskets` and `aprioriList`?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: itemBaskets is a dictionary and aprioriList is a list.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] that shows what `i` and `j` are. It seems they are something that cannot be `sorted` ( You cannot sort an int ).